# How to install s3fs in Ubuntu Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I'm trying to set up a Docker Ubuntu image which has an AWS s3 bucket mounted as a local filesystem, using s3fs. There are several guides, mostly like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598916/aws-s3fs-how-to), which say to install various apt packages, set up a `~/.passwd-s3fs` file, and then run `s3fs`. However in recent versions of Ubuntu (I've tried 16.04, 18.04, & latest), it says I should install the package `linux-headers-4.9.184-linuxkit` -- however that doesn't seem available anywhere. I'm stuck.

I've got it working fine on my local Mac, but I can't get it going on my Ubuntu image.

```sh
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y awscli
$ apt-get install -y automake autotools-dev fuse g++ git libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfuse-dev libssl- dev libxml2-dev make pkg-config kmod
$ apt-get install -y s3fs
$ echo key:secretkey > ~/.passwd-s3fs && chmod 0600 ~/.passwd-s3fs
$ mkdir /s3mountpoint
$ s3fs mybucketname /s3mountpoint
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
$ modprobe fuse
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.9.184-linuxkit/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.184-linuxkit
```

I've also tried cloning & manually-compiling `https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse.git` but that gives me the same error.

How can I either run `fuse` ok, or find the relevant legacy `kernel-headers` package, in order to run `s3fs` successfully on Ubuntu?

Comment: I worked around this by revising the whole thing to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so that the awssdk is available by default, and the s3 integration works out of the box. Obviously that's not a real solution to the problem, but it's probably a better solution for my use case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone run into same issue described here and got into this post, I was able to solve the problem with running the docker with `--privileged` flag.